# Adjust styling of web3uikit element

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, web3uikit

I want to apply custom CSS to a `<ConnectButton>` element from web3uikit. I added a div around it with a CSS class ("myDiv") and tried to target it via CSS like: `.myDiv button { color:red !important }`

But the changes are not applied to the button. How can I apply styling to the this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing this using an [interactive example on the web3ui github docs](https://web3ui.github.io/web3uikit/?path=/story/1-web3-parse-connectbutton--default) I noticed that the `button` has a `span` inside that controls the text color.

For the button background color this would be enough

```
.myDiv button { background-color:red !important }
```

However if you want to change the text color you would have to change the selector to the following:

```
.myDiv button span { color:red !important }
```

See the following image as example, I hope it can visually explain it better. As you can see, I added the specific button shaping styles to the `button` element. But the text styling to the `span` inside.

[image]

Let me know if this solved your issue, if not, let me know, and I will look into it further.

Comment: As also showcased the color property on the `<button>` with !important does not change the color of the span that has color purple.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to put the CSS in the global.css instead of Home.module.css

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question please flag it as the answer

Comment: I did. And the reputation can be given in 2 hours from now